# Ввод параметров при выполнении MySQL запроса

Tags: mysql

В Access есть возможность вводить вручную параметры запроса во время его выполнения, выглядит это так:

```
SELECT f1, f2
FROM table_name
WHERE coins.f1=[Название:] OR f2=[Код:];
```

Во время запуска выполнения запроса необходимо ввести соответственно или название или код, чтобы произошла выборка из БД по конкретным параметрам. Вопрос, как в MySQL сделать тоже самое?

Comment: никак. это возможности не самой БД, а среды для работы с ней. Может конечно есть какие то среды разработки это позволяющие, но я их не встречал. Можно использовать переменные: `set @x:=1; select ... where abc=@x`. Но это явно не то же самое, никто у вас значения запрашивать не будет, set вы должны написать сами.

Comment: так в том же Navicat во Views по сути тоже самое как в Access, т.е. по логике перед выполнением и параметр туда запихнуть можно? Раз это возможность среды для работы с ней, тогда переформулирую вопрос: Можно ли сделать аналог запроса с вводом параметра в Navicat? Если да, то как.

Comment: правильно заданный вопрос гуглу дал следующее: https://community.navicat.com/forum/navicat-product/navicat-for-oracle/3008-bind-variables-in-the-query-editor

Comment: @Mike http://joxi.ru/1A5vBl0CK3jP1r возможно в далеком 15-м это и работало, но на сегодняшний день выдает ошибку :(

Comment: там в примере вроде пробела после $ не было ...

Comment: я пробовал разные варианты, на скрин попал этот, сорри что не сравнил перед тем как скрин делать, вот: http://joxi.ru/Q2KG9K3s91le12 т.е. пробел ни на что не влият в данном случае.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос снят, оказалось это баг конкретно моей версии Navicat 12.0.16. Обновился до Navicat 12.0.23 и все заработало именно в том виде, в котором описано по ссылке от @Mike. Т.е.

```
SELECT f1, f2
FROM table_name
WHERE coins.f1=[$Название:] OR f2=[$Код:];
```